# How to free(a)?

Tags: c

I am doing leetocde. First question is Two Sum: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/description/

I submit solution with c code:

```
/**
* Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
*/
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target) {
    int *a = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0;i<numsSize;i++){
        for(int j = i+1;(j<numsSize && j != i);j++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
            a[0] = i;
            a[1] = j;
            return a;
            }
        }
    }
     return NULL;
}
```

My soluution be accepted.

The complete c code is:

```
/* my solution to Two Sum */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TARGET 9


int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target) {
    int *a = (int*)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0;i<numsSize;i++){
        for(int j = i+1;(j<numsSize && j != i);j++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                a[0] = i;
                a[1] = j;
                return a;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int n,target = TARGET;
    int a[]={2, 7, 11, 15};
//  int a[]={2,25,10,7,11,15,21,60};        // test data
    int *result = NULL;

    n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    result = twoSum(a,n,target);

    if(result != NULL)
        printf("%d %d\n",result[0],result[1]);
    else
        printf("No elements that satisfy the condition\n");

    return 0;
}

/*
 * output:
 * 0 1
 */
```

I run command:

```
gcc two-sum.c -o two-sum
./two-sum
```

It outputs : 0 1

But I find my code have a bug that in twoSum function "a" is not be free.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The complement only makes sense when you specify how long your data type is. If it's 4 bits, then for `0xf` it's `0x0`. If it's 8 bits, then for `0xf` it's `0xf0`.

Your representation of -6 is going to be either `0xfa`, `0xfffa`, `0xfffffffa`, or longer, depending on how many bytes long your value is.

Comment: how do I quickly calculate -6 with The complement of 0xf is 0x0,the complement of 0xa is 0x5 and 0xfffffffa relationship?

Comment: @MichaelSmith https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Converting_to_two's_complement_representation